# Flutter & Firebase : Failed to get data from firebase sub-collection into my Stream

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, state-management

I am trying to get my data info my stream. For some reason, I couldn't do it. It doesn't even print out my inner print statement "print("Inside snapshot")".

Please have a look on my code and tell me what to do to solve this issue.
I am looking forward to hearing all of your opinions and ideas.Thank you in advance.

Terminal Message

```
W/DynamiteModule( 3822): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 3822): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 3822): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/flutter ( 3822): Inside _messageList
```

Model

```
class Conversation {
  final DateTime date;
  final String message;
  final String sendby;

  Conversation({this.date, this.message, this.sendby});
}
```

Screen Code

```
return StreamBuilder<List<Conversation>>(
        stream: User_DatabaseService(uid: uid).chatroomMesssages,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          List<Conversation> messageList = snapshot.data ?? [];
          messageList.forEach((message) {
        print("${message.date} ${message.message} ${message.sendby}");
      });
//-----
}
```

Database Code

```
    // collection reference
  final CollectionReference chatroomCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chatrooms');
// all conversation
      List<Conversation> _messageList(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        print("Inside _messageList");
    
        return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
          print("Inside snapshot");
          final dataInfo = doc.data();
          print(dataInfo['date']);
          
          return Conversation(
            date: dataInfo['date'] ?? null,
            sendby: dataInfo['sendBy'] ?? null,
            message: dataInfo['message'] ?? null,
          );
        }).toList();
      }
    
      //Get all conversation
      Stream<List<Conversation>> get chatroomMesssages {
        //print('in allUserData');
        print("Inside getChatroomMesssages");
        return userCollection
            .doc('devil@yahoo.com_punreach@yahoo.com')
            .collection("chats")
            .snapshots()
            .map(_messageList);
      }
```

Firebase
[image]

Comment: Is there any error, or any other relevant output? What's `userCollection`?

Comment: It's supposed to give me the sub collection data. But It doesn't

Comment: Oh yeah I used the wrong name.

Comment: Write your answer! I will give you my points

Comment: I just did! Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "this collection does not exist" error in Firebase. You can refer to nonexistent collections and they arrive empty. You are allowed to refer to nonexistent collections, that's how you create them in the first place.

Your error here is that you are using your `userCollection`, which does not have any of these. In your screenshot we see `chatrooms`, so you should use a `chatroomsCollection` instead, which actually has the data that we see in the screenshot.

Comment: I will be able give you after 22 hours

Comment: is it time? :D.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message, it is actually quite informative:

> type 'Conversation' is not a subtype of type 'List'

Take look at this line; if `snapshot.data` is null, then you're trying to assign an object of wrong type:

```
List<Conversation> messageList = snapshot.data ?? Conversation();
```

---

Edit: again, please, read the actual error message.

> The method 'forEach' was called on null.

Now, you're assigning `null` to the same variable if `snapshot.data` is null, here: `List<Conversation> messageList = snapshot.data ?? null;`, then you're calling `.forEach` on it.

Comment: Oh, that's just my previous code. I changed it. Please have a look on a new one.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That I assigned null. But that's not the point. Cus if it has some value, it will change from null to something. But I didn't

Comment: Yes, that *is* the point. Because it is null, therefore an exception is thrown. You should assign an empty list to it, or handle such cases differently, depending on your design requirements. I'm not really sure how to explain it further.

Comment: Sir, I changed it as you said. And now, I still can't get the value into my stream.  How can you explain this then?